# custom views handler to show dynamic all profile fields

Tags: views, users

I'm using D6 and I like to have a view that shows all user profile fields. The situation now is, that you have to tic all  fields that you like to show. I'm using [OG profiles](http://drupal.org/project/og_profiles) and the user is able to add profile fields to it's group. In addition to that, I need a view that get all fields that are belonging to a group (automatic).

What is the starting point for me? Found that .. http://techblog.zabuchy.net/2010/non-database-field-in-custom-drupal-views-2/

But how to start?

pseudo code:

get all field belonging to a group (arg(1))
and disp

Answer (score 0):

This is probably done better in a preprocess function in a theme instead. However if you want to do it you ned to create a handler, something like this:

```
class og_group_handler_field extends views_handler_field {
  function render() {
    $og = arg(1);
    $output
    // Load the group and add to $output what needs to be displayed
   return $output;
 }
 function query() {
   // Make sure we don't add anything to the queue.
  }
}
```

and the add the handler to a table like nodes

```
function module_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  $data['node']['og_all_group_fields_from_arg_1'] = array(
    'field' => array(
      'title' => 'title',
      'help' => 'Help Text',
      'handler' => 'og_group_handler_field',
    ),
  );
}
```

For Drupal 6 you also need to register the handler, the link you posted illustrates how this is done.